# Levenberg-Marquardt made scale invariant with diagonal matrix?

Tags: optimization, least-squares, nonlinear-regression, gradient-descent, generalized-least-squares

From the paper [Improvements to the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm for nonlinear least-squares minimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.5885)

> We now describe how to choose an effective damping matrix $D^TD$. Levenberg originally suggested
> an additive damping strategy, corresponding to = $D^TD = \delta$, the identity. It has since been suggested that
> a multiplicative damping strategy in which $D^TD$ is a diagonal matrix with entries equal to the diagonal
> entries of $J^TJ$ would more accurately capture the scaling of the several parameters. This method for
> choosing parameter scaling has the property that the algorithm is invariant to rescaling parameters, which
> is to say if the parameters of the model were replaced by the parameters $\tilde{\theta}= \lambda \theta$ for some scaling factors $\lambda_i$, then the sequence of iterates, i.e. values of the cost function, produced by the algorithm would be left unchanged.

Is there a proof for why $(J^TJ + \lambda \texttt{diag}(J^TJ))^{-1}$ makes LMA scale invariant?

The Eigen-values of of this matrix would look something like this

$\bigg(\sigma_j + \lambda \frac{\partial C^2}{\partial \theta_j^2} \bigg)^{-1}$

but I'm not sure what they would look like for $\tilde{\theta}$.

Comment: That term, by itself, is not scale-invariant.  When multiplied by $\nabla C$ in the algorithm it is scale *covariant,* which means it behaves exactly like $\theta$ under a change of scale. This can be appreciated, intuitively, as an application of ["quantity calculus"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantity_calculus).

Comment: @whuber thanks for the reply. Can you please, in simple terms, explain the difference between scale invariance and scale covariance? I believe the product you are referring to looks something like $\bigg(\sigma_j + \lambda \frac{\partial C^2}{\partial \theta_j^2} \bigg)^{-1} \frac{\partial C}{\partial \theta_j}$ ?

Comment: Additionally (maybe this warrants a new question), if we use some $D \neq \delta$ in the normal equations, does that mean we can no longer do weighted least squares regression?

Comment: "Invariance" and "covariance" have different meanings, depending on the author and application.  But in math and physics (and much of stats), a function $f$ is *invariant* under a group $G$ acting on its domain $X$ when $f(gx)=f(x)$ for all $g\in G$ and $x\in X,$ whereas (to simplify a bit) it is *covariant* when $G$ also acts on the range of $f$ and $f(gx)=gf(x)$ for all $x$ and $g.$ *Eg,* $G$ can be the multiplicative positive real numbers, in which case an invariant function with domain $\mathbb{R}^n$ is of the form $f(|x|)$ and homogeneous polynomials are examples of covariant functions.